# Why does firebase return undefined in my component but I can see the object in console.log when I read my database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, next.js

Im using Next.js and Typescript.

I'm trying to implement a custom hook for reading my data and outputting the object. I'm using the firebase realtime database. My data is an array of objects. Firebase returns an object of objects with .val() which I then convert to an array of objects in the custom hook, but I cannot pass it to my component for some reason. I can console.log the new array of objects, but can't return it to my component which reads undefined when I console.log it at the component.

I notice that sometimes when I edit the code and it auto-reloads, the console.log for my component works.

Here's my custom hook snippet and component trying to call it. Thanks!

Custom Hook Snippet:

```
// ... rest of hook is above this snippe (the hook is useFirebaseAuth())
  const readBlogData = () => {
    const db = getDatabase(app);
    const dbRef = ref(db, "blogs");
    let newArrObj;
    onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
      newArrObj = Object.values(snapshot.val());
      console.log(newArrObj); // I can see the array of objects in console.log
    });

    return newArrObj;
  };

  return { login, logout, loginStatus, writeBlogData, readBlogData };
}
```

Component:

```
export default function BlogSection() {
  const { readBlogData } = useFirebaseAuth();
  console.log(readBlogData()); // console.log shows undefined

  return (
    <section className={styles.blogSection}>
      <Card className={styles.blogsContainer}>
        <h5>Blogs</h5>
        <Paginate blogs={DUMMY_DATA} />
      </Card>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code in the callback for onValue happens *after* the `return newArrObj` line.

You probably want to set it on state in your hook and return that state so the consumer can react to it.

```
const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);

// then

onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
      newArrObj = Object.values(snapshot.val());
      setBlogs(newArrObj);
    });

// then

return { login, logout, loginStatus, writeBlogData, readBlogData, blogData: blogs };
```

Program the consumer to fetch the data and display the response

```
const Consumer = () => {
  const { blogData, readBlogData } = useWhatever();

  useEffect(() => readBlogData(), []); // Tell the hook to get some data

// blogData will initially be an empty array
// and then eventually will have some elements
return blogData.length ? <p>{JSON.stringify(blogData)</p> : null;
};
```

Comment: How will I trigger the request in the consumer? Will I call readBlogData() and then blogData? When i tried that I got Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: Make sure your readBlogData() call is not inside the function body, else it will happen every render.